# Deploying Excel VBA Add-Ins

Tags: vba, excel

What are the options to deploy Add-In developed in Excel VBA? There is only one xlam file to be deployed.

I find the process of go to "File -> Backstage > choose Options > Select Add-Ins > Manage Excel Add-ins click Go > Click Browse at Add-Ins dialog box > browse to the folder that contains the xlam file > Open" etc. may be too cumbersome or difficult for some of my users.

It begins with download the xlam file from a website. So I will not know exactly the location of the downloaded xlam could be.

Comment: I do realise the user can just double click on the xlam file and the add-in will be able to use for that session until the Excel is closed.

Comment: According to [How do I deploy a VBA Excel Add-In (foo.xlam) using an msi installer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308744/how-do-i-deploy-a-vba-excel-add-in-foo-xlam-using-an-msi-installer), you can add a new register value in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Add-in Manager`.

Comment: I saw the post. I just wonder exactly how it can be done by adding a registry value. When a user double click on the xlam? or you need to package the xlam with window installer?

Thanks for the patience, I am an amateur programmer works entirely on Excel VBA only.

Comment: You could write a batch script that uses `regedit` to add a new register value

Comment: The answer by Alban Lopez in the same post seem plausible. Will try it with these steps

1. when user double click on xlam a script will extract the c: drive serial number and check if this serial number is already in a specific cell of the hidden sheet of this xlam.
2. if no, the script recommended by Alban Lopez will run to install the add-in. Then it will record the c drive serial number in that specific cell of the hidden sheet.

3. if yes, the script will not run. Since this xlam had already been installed.

Comment: Thanks z. will try this too.